# Angular2 NgModel fails in two way bindings

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a GET XMLHttpRequest done against a service giving me as response  the following JSON payload :

```
{_id: "5aa1358d32eba9e34dd9f280", source: "Avengers", target: "Iron Man", enemies: "Actor"}
```

I have the object hero in src/app :

```
export class Hero {
  _id: number;
  target: string;
  source: string;
  enemies: string;
}
```

The code in the TS component to get the data :

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      const id = params['id'];
      this.getHero(id);
    });

  }

  getHero(id: string): void {

    this.heroService.getHero(id)
      .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
  }
```

Code of the method in the service:

```
 getHero(id: string): Observable<Hero> {
    // Todo: send the message _after_ fetching the hero
    this.messageService.add(`HeroService: fetched hero id=${id}`);
    const url = `${this.herodetailUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Hero>(url);
  }
```

Here is my code in the view :

```
<label>name:
  <input [(ngModel)]="hero.target" (input)="hero.target =
  $event.target.value" placeholder="target" /> </label>
<label>group:
  <input [(ngModel)]="hero.source" (input)="hero.source =
  $event.target.value" placeholder="source" /> </label>
<label>enemies:
  <input [(ngModel)]="hero.enemies" (input)="hero.enemies =
  $event.target.value" placeholder="enemies" /> </label>
```

The binding doesn't work

In my form elements i see the name of my placeholder. Not the value

Regards

Laurent

Comment: What do you see when you type `{{hero | json}}` in the template. I'm not sure you're correctly retrieving your hero.

Comment: You don't need (input) while using [(ngModel)]

Comment: Have you debugged to see if hero object is fetched ?

Comment: I show the {{ hero | json }} and it's ok i see [ { "_id": "5aa1358d32eba9e34dd9f280", "source": "Avengers", "target": "Iron Man", "enemies": "Actor" } ]

Answer (score 0):

```
<label>name:
  <input [(ngModel)]="hero.target" (input)="hero.target =
  $event.target.value" placeholder="target" /> </label>
<label>group:
  <input [(ngModel)]="hero.source" (input)="hero.source =
  $event.target.value" placeholder="source" /> </label>
<label>enemies:
  <input [(ngModel)]="hero.enemies" (input)="hero.enemies =
  $event.target.value" placeholder="enemies" /> </label>
```

You don't need **(input)="hero.target = $event.target.value"** when you use  as this **[(ngModel)]**

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is an array of an object, So i modified my view as is : {{ hero[0].target | uppercase }} and so on for each form component. Now it works as is :

```
>   <div><span>id: </span>{{hero[0]._id}}</div>   <div>
>     <label>name:
>       <input [(ngModel)]="hero[0].target"  placeholder="target"/>
>     </label>
>     <label>group:
>       <input [(ngModel)]="hero[0].source"  placeholder="source"/>
>     </label>
>     <label>enemies:
>       <input [(ngModel)]="hero[0].enemies"  placeholder="enemies"/>
>     </label>
```

Now the binding works